# Add file to input type file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input, croppie

I am using a library called `Croppie.js` that crops images. What I am trying to do is :

- Upload a picture thanks to an input type=file that only accepts image files
- Edit it thanks to `Croppie.js` methods
- Put the generated image back into the file input, replacing the original image

`Croppie.js` is able to generate a blob thanks to its function `result`. Therefore here is what it would look like :

```
$("#confirm-photo-edit").click(function(){
    $("#photo-to-crop").croppie('result', 'blob').then(function(editedImg){
        // Here something like $("#photo-input").files.push(editedImg);
    });
});
```

Thus my questions are :

- Do I have to convert from Blob to File ?
- How do I replace the original image that's in the input by the edited one, `editedImg` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't think it's possible due to security issues. Input type file is restricted in a lot of ways because of that. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: What you can do is send a text representation of the file (base64 for example) to a normal (hidden) input to store the cropped image.

Comment: Oh, that sounds pretty good, yeah. Croppie can also genereate base64 images. But how do I send that to an input ? Would it be a text input ? Then, I'd just need to set its value to `editedImg` ?

Comment: assuming `editedImg` hold the base64 representation of the img you can do `$('#normalTextInput').val(editedImg);`

Comment: I had to cut a part of the string with `substring` as `croppie('result', 'base64')` also returns `data:image/png;base64,` in the resulting string, but it worked like a charm as soon as I did this. You can put your comment as an answer if you want me to accept it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible the access the file itself of an input with the type file in most browsers. This is because of security reasons. However it is possible do store your file as a character based string representation. For Example a base64 string. Almost every programming environment has something to decode base64 too.